# Drawing custom sprites onto a button in monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, spritebatch, spritefont

I'm using monogame. I want to overlay Text onto one of my button images, but I want to use the image way of drawing;

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
```

so that I can control how the text is handled inside the bounds of the button image rectangle, like trim excess.

Is there a way to draw strings using the fontsprite, without using the `spriteBatch.DrawString` method, or is there more to this method that I haven't learned yet? It just seems limiting from its input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Font.MeasureString` to get the width and height of a string as a `Vector2`. You can subtract half of it from the center position of a `Rectangle` and you get your centered text.